# Total delay of cascade FIR filters

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response

I have a doubt regarding the total delay in terms of taps for cascade filters.

Imagine that I have an SOS IIR Filter (2 delays) and an FIR filter of 10 taps (10 delays) and another of 20 taps (20 delays). The total delay of the group is 20 + 10 + 2=32 delays or is it the maximum of all of the as the sample does travel along the net.

I guess, if my rationale is not wrong, that the steady state response of the whole net is reached at the sum of all of them as you need to have stable output from first stage, then second stage and then third stage.

Comment: In my opinion, the *"total delay"* of the cascade of a bunch of linear, time-invariant filters, whether they be IIR or FIR, is simply the sum of the delays of each filter in the series, **however** that delay is defined. *Total Group Delay* is the sum of the individual group delays of each filter. *Total Phase Delay* is the sum of the individual phase delays of each filter. If the IIR filters are designed to maximize the phase linearity and if the FIR filters are symmetric about the mid-sample of the FIR impulse response, this overall total delay will be roughly constant for most frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The throughput, like Marcus said, is $1$, since for each input sample there’s an output sample (unless you’re doing block processing, which I’m assuming you’re not).

As far as group delay, it is the sum of the individual group delays for each filter (**if they're LTI!**)

Here's an example:

[image]

---

Matlab code to reproduce:

```matlab
N1 = 10;
N2 = 20; 
h1 = fir1(N1, 0.8); % FIR1
h2 = fir1(N2, 0.2); % FIR2
[b,a] = butter(4, [0.4, 0.6], 'bandpass'); % IIR

imp = [1, zeros(1, 500)]; % Impulse
    
% impulse response of the cascade
out = filter(h1, 1, imp);
out = filter(h2, 1, out);
out = filter(b, a, out);

% individual group delays
[g1, w] = grpdelay(h1,1);
g2 = grpdelay(h2,1);
g3 = grpdelay(b,a);

% group delay of the impulse response
gout_imp = grpdelay(out,1);

% sum of individual group delays
gout_sum = g1+g2+g3;

figure
hold on
plot(w/pi, g1)
plot(w/pi, g2)
plot(w/pi, g3)
plot(w/pi, gout_imp, 'linewidth', 2)
plot(w/pi, gout_sum, 'linewidth', 2, 'linestyle','--')
legend('FIR1', 'FIR2', 'IIR', 'cascade', 'sum of individual group delays')
grid on
ylim([0 35])
xlim([5e-3, 1])
xlabel('normalized freq (\times\pi rad/sample)')
ylabel('Group delay (samples)')
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not correct. The actual delay that you describe depends on the signal component's frequency and on the actual filters implemented using these delays!
The technical term you need to research here is *group delay*.

Also, nothing says this system with IIRs even *has* a steady-state response. Hint: if you give an impulse to a system that is *IIR*, then that system *will have Infinite Impulse Response*. There's no point at which the system will be "done" handling the effects of that single non-zero sample that you inserted in an endless stream of zeros.

Comment: What I have described might be the sample delay? or how that is called

Comment: you described group delay, as far as I understand your question, and misunderstood it! think about this: in your SOS IIR, your sample gets "fed back". So, how long does it take to travel through that? Right, it takes anywhere from 2 delays to infinity. It doesn't necessarily produce any "first output" after 2 delays, either, because it might cancel with the 2 samples after it. That's the thing – you **need** to look at the frequencies of your signal and at the group delay at that frequency.

Comment: Right, that's clear. Great. Then, the "system" delays, or the number of taps the filter needs to fill the buffer, does it have a name for it?

Comment: do you mean throughput? That'd be 1, because your filters consume one sample each iteration, I'd say, and one sample comes out per iteration. Honestly, bit confused by *what* you want to describe – does this have to do with your assumption of a steady-state response?

Comment: Let me elaborate on that. the filters have a length in taps. For example, for the filter of 10 taps, it takes 10 samples to fill the buffer. Is that ammount of time for filling the buffers connected to any measure, metric or terminology?

Comment: *the filters have a length in taps* no! The first I in "IIR" literally means "does not have finite length in taps". And the buffer *is* always already filled – maybe with zeros or random data – but I feel you're again aiming at a steady state which does not necessarily exist.

Comment: *//"Also, nothing says this system with IIRs even has a steady-state response."//*  I know what you're trying to say, Marcus, but this is misleading.  Normally, at least in the context of electrical engineering, *"steady-state response"* means, in the limit - long after the switch is thrown - the response of the system to a sinusoid of a known frequency.  The steady-state response is the sinusoid that you get in the output after the transient response has decayed to a negligible level.  Even in your example, because the input amplitude of the sinusoid is zero, so also is the output amplitude.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yeah, it'd be fair to explicitly exclude IIRs that become oscillators or completely diverge

Comment: yeah, i guess you're right.  An IIR that blows up does not have a steady-state response because its transient response never decays to zero.  It never gets over its transient.  If it never gets over the transient, then there is so steady-state.  (Normally, when I think about questions like this, I assume strictly stable LTI systems where all poles lie fully ***inside*** the unit circle.

Comment: yeah, that makes things easier, but don't forget you might want to actually have a zero **on** the unit circle (say, to kill a line hum at a specific frequency). Then asking, "hm, what's the delay for exactly this frequency" could be answered with "you pick what you like, won't matter", but for frequencies *close* to that zero, things might not be as nice, just due to numerical accuracy.